# Unknown column 'item.Item_id' in 'where clause'?

Tags: mysql

The Price is from table item while the payment_amount is from table invoice.What is wrong with my code?

```
UPDATE invoice
SET payment_amount = Quantity_bought*(SELECT Price
                                      FROM item)
                                      WHERE item.Item_id = invoice.Item_id;
```

> #1054 - Unknown column 'item.Item_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: The ) should be after the where clause..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move ')' at the end

```
UPDATE invoice
SET payment_amount = Quantity_bought*(SELECT Price
                                      FROM item
                                      WHERE item.Item_id = 
                                            invoice.Item_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql syntax is incorrect.

Correct one has been written below.

UPDATE invoice
SET payment_amount = Quantity_bought*(SELECT Price
                                      FROM item
                                      WHERE item.Item_id = invoice.Item_id);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that using join and find enough examples if you google `How to update using JOIN in MySQL`. Though it's answered already you can choose one easy way using `JOIN` as below:

```
UPDATE invoice
INNER JOIN item ON item.Item_id = invoice.Item_id 
SET payment_amount = (Quantity_bought * Price);
```